# Bind D3.js event to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, coffeescript, force-layout

Since I'm using D3.js via coffee, following codes works fine:

```
$ ->
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .on('tick', -> alert('tick triggered'))
```

But these don't, since at that time there isn't any `tick` function:

```
$ ->
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .on('tick', tick)
  tick = ->
    alert('tick triggered')
```

So is there any way I can bind a D3 event to a function?

BTW, I tried

```
$ ->
  tick = ->
    alert('tick triggered')
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .on('tick', tick)
```

but some `Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"` thing wrong while tick running.

Comment: please upload your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: `tick` is `undefined` when you try to use it in the second one, the third one is fine. Your `NaN` problem is something else.

Comment: @muistooshort Yep, that's the point!

Comment: What tries to parse that pile of NaNs?

Answer (score 0):

try change here

```
tick = ->
```

use this

```
tick: =>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ->
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .on('tick', tick)
  tick = ->
    alert('tick triggered')
```

means

```
$(function() {
  var force, tick;
  force = d3.layout.force().on('tick', tick);
  return tick = function() {
    return alert('tick triggered');
  };
});
```

here `return tick = function(){}` is an Illegal return statement.

Maybe you need add `tick` or `null` to the end of Coffee codes.
like this.

```
$ ->
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .on('tick', tick)
  tick = -> alert('tick triggered')
  null
//////////////
$(function() {
  var force, tick;
  force = d3.layout.force().on('tick', tick);
  tick = function() {
    return alert('tick triggered');
  };
  return null;
});
```